# Right knowledge and right relase or right release and right knowledge

Tags: theravada

In ten Noble path the sequence is right knowledge and right release. (Samma Nana and samma vimutti)

In SN 12.23 it says:

Dispassion is a vital condition for freedom.

virāgūpanisā vimutti,

Freedom is a vital condition for the knowledge of ending.

vimuttūpanisaṃ khayeñāṇaṃ.

https://suttacentral.net/sn12.23/en/sujato

Answer (score 3):

SN 12.23 says:

- Khaye**ñāṇa**ṃ (knowledge of destruction of defilements) has freedom (from defilements) as its condition.
- Freedom (from defilements) has dispassion, disillusionment & yathābhūta**ñāṇa**dassanan (truly knowing and seeing) as its conditions.

Therefore, if following the sequence of dhammas in SN 12.23, "right knowledge" ("samma ñāṇa") in MN 117 would be yathābhūta**ñāṇa**dassanan and not khaye**ñāṇa**ṃ.

Answer (score 0):

Right Knowledge (sammāñāṇaṃ) come first. Then come Right Release (sammāvimutti). However those two are only for an Arahat. For the sekha person (one who is practicing the Noble Eight Fold Path) the first eight.

https://suttacentral.net/mn117/en/bodhi

> “Therein, bhikkhus, right view comes first. And how does right view
>   come first? In one of right view, right intention comes into being; in
>   one of right intention, right speech comes into being; in one of right
>   speech, right action comes into being; in one of right action, right
>   livelihood comes into being; in one of right livelihood, right effort
>   comes into being; in one of right effort, right mindfulness comes into
>   being; in one of right mindfulness, right concentration comes into
>   being; in one of right concentration, right knowledge comes into
>   being; in one of right knowledge, right deliverance comes into being.
>   Thus, bhikkhus, the path of the disciple in higher training possesses
>   eight factors, the arahant possesses ten factors.

If you want to learn how to develop the Noble Eight Fold Path, [take a look at this](https://visuddhimagga.info/download.php?file=https://anaalaya.blob.core.windows.net/dhamma2018/M_E_Eightfoldpath_30_03_2018.mp4)

Answer (score 0):

Upasaka, interested,

Knowledge of release *khayeñāṇa*, or *Dukkha-nirodha-gāminiyā paṭipadāya ñāṇaṃ* (Knowledge of the way leading to the cessation of suffering), is the effect of the path. Now knowing this, of cause needs to attain certain liberation *vimutti* at first place. Once attained this knowledge guiding to certain *[vimutti](http://accesstoinsight.eu/en/dictionary/vimutti)*, can be reproduced.

There is no such as a contradiction, but is simply a change of perspective, one toward fruit, and one having left fruit behind.

Other then mentioned in other answers, release and knowledge of release are not only something that occurs only to an Arahat, but to certain extent for all other stages of awakening. In full extant and so also full repeat-able, of course only for an Arahat. Knowledge at the "end", with the breaking up of the body, will then be abounded and final *ceto-vimutti*, *pañña-vimutti* attained. Release is the only left then.

*(Note that this is not given for trade, exchange, stacks and entertainment but as a means toward escape from this wheel here)*

Comment: Venerable Johann. "Khayeñāṇa" means "knowledge of destruction". Regards

Comment: Or "knowledge of ending", yes, Brahman Dhammadhatu.